# Java survey program results not calculating correctly

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm looking to create a Java program that uses an array, a `for` loop and a method to conduct a survey of 3 questions to 4 people. Each question will have a yes or a no answer. The overall results of the survey should be in percentage format.

I

Comment: Also, what does "not calculating correctly" mean?  What output are you getting? What were you expecting to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First things first**: by convention, Java classes always have a capitalized letter. So rename `survey` to `Survey`.

**Secondly**, move all your variables/constants to the top of your code. It makes it easier to read. For instance, `person` should be declared either on the first line of your `main` method, or even as a constant in your class.

**Thirdly**, don't use variables for values you should derive. For instance, you declare `int NumberQuestions = 3;` but in fact that's the length of the array of questions. So use the length instead. You do use it to initialize the array, so instead, switch to a different way of initializing the array, e.g.:

```
    // Number of Questions
    String[] question = new String[] {
        "Have you ever like shopping online? ",
        "Did you start your christmas shopping? ",
        "Are you waiting for Black Friday sales? "};
```

This might be a matter of personal taste, but I prefer to use `while...do` rather than `do...while`.

### Your actual mistake

Another big warning: remember that array indices start with zero (0) in Java, not 1. Yet, you start saving responses for user #1 in row #1 thus leaving row #0 empty.

However, when you do the math (average...), you bring back the first row, thus you're not getting what you're expecting. I was wondering why you were creating an array that is `person + 1` but that's probably because you were trying to avoid an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

### Other stuff you can simplify

You can also simplify this `if`/then/`else` statement:

```
if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    answer[personIndex][questionIndex] = 1;
} else {
    answer[personIndex][questionIndex] = 0;
}
```

Which can be simply written as:

```
answer[personIndex][questionIndex] = userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") ? 1 : 0;
```

### The full working code

```
package eu.webfarmr;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Survey {
    // Number of people
    private final static int PERSON_COUNT = 4;

    // Questions
    private final static String[] QUESTIONS = new String[] { 
        "Have you ever like shopping online? ",
        "Did you start your christmas shopping? ",
        "Are you waiting for Black Friday sales? " };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Yes or No:");

        // people Loop
        int[][] answer = new int[PERSON_COUNT][QUESTIONS.length];
        for (int personIndex = 0; personIndex < PERSON_COUNT; personIndex++) {
            System.out.println("person " + personIndex);

            // Question Loop
            for (int questionIndex = 0; questionIndex < QUESTIONS.length; questionIndex++) {
                // Answer yes or no only
                boolean valid = false;
                do {
                    System.out.print(QUESTIONS[questionIndex]);
                    String userInput = in.next();
                    valid = userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no");
                    if (!valid) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter Yes or No");
                    } else {
                        answer[personIndex][questionIndex] = userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")? 1:0;
                    }
                } while (!valid);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // survey results
        System.out.println("Survey Results\t\t\t\t Yes\t No");

        for (int i = 0; i < QUESTIONS.length; i++) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < PERSON_COUNT; j++)
                total += answer[j][i];

            int percent = (total * 100) / PERSON_COUNT;
            System.out.println(QUESTIONS[i] + "\t " + percent + "%\t " + (100 - percent) + "%");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a matrix of 5 rows and 4 columns, that the main problem.

Change the first loop to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < person; i++)
```

and the matrix creation to:

```
int[][] answer = new int[person][NumberQuestions];
```